# using a function to write the input of a text field to the document when all forms are submitted

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

```
        <script src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script>

        function saveScore (score) {
score=document.input.$('.inputright').value
        $('submit').click(function(event) {
          $('<div>')
            .append(score)
            .appendTo('.wincolumn');

        });
        }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <form name= "myform">
        <input class="inputright" type="text" value="Team?" onfocus='value=""' onblur="value='Team?'" onclick="saveScore(score)">
        </form>

    <div id="bottomcontainer">
           <div class="personalcolumns" id="niccolumn">
               <div class="playername"> Nic Meiring </div>
              <div class="wincolumn WLRcolumn"> </div>
               <div class="losscolumn WLRcolumn"> </div>
               <div class="resultcolumn WLRcolumn"> </div>
            </div>
    </body>
```

I want to take the input in the text field called Team? and write it to the column with the class `.teamcolumn`

2 main problems(I think)

1. allowing the text field to have a default value of "Team?" but then switching its value to the input when the `onclick` method is called (and therefore the function is called)
2. how to best write to the document from within that function. `document.writeln()` maybe?

Thanks

Comment: A few problems with your example code: 1) the input field has no name 2) I don't see any elements in your example with the class "teamcolumn" 3) the event handlers you placed on the input field always overwrite any input with the text "Team?"

What is it exactly that you're trying to do?

Comment: @ManseUK I apologize. I didn't know. Went back and accepted the answers that people helped with me. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Nic M Without commenting your code, answer to #2 is: don't use `document.write()` through functions in the same document. This method will clear your document before it writes in it. jQuery and DHTML include plenty of tools to write document without loosing all other content.

Comment: @j08691 Thanks. I fixed the .teamcolumn instead of .wincolumn (typo) and added names to the input fields. i searched around a bit more and think i need to use a utility called keyboard scanner that scans keyboard input and overwrites the default value i assign with the one that is typed in. does this sound right? The end result should write that to the document in the .teamcolumn.

Comment: @Teemu makes sense. will look into it more. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a demo for you at **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5Kh76/)**. The input field defaults to "Team?" if no text is entered, however if text is entered then it is not changed. If the input field loses focus and it is empty, it returns to "Team?". Once the field is blurred the value (if not "Team?") is then appended to the .wincolumn div. I removed your savescore function and all your inline event handlers.

jQuery:

```
$('input[name="foo"]').change(function() {
    $('div.wincolumn').html($(this).val());
}).focus(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 'Team?') {
        $(this).val('');
    }
}).blur(function() {
    if (!$(this).val()) {
        $(this).val('Team?');
    }
})
```

HTML:

```
<form name= "myform">
<input name="foo" class="inputright" type="text" value="Team?">
</form>

<div id="bottomcontainer">
   <div class="personalcolumns" id="niccolumn">
       <div class="playername"> Nic Meiring </div>
       <div class="wincolumn WLRcolumn"> </div>
       <div class="losscolumn WLRcolumn"> </div>
       <div class="resultcolumn WLRcolumn"> </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked. When I try to apply it to my project I am having trouble getting any of the jquery to work. do i have it linked correctly? <head> <script src="jquery.js"></script> <script language="JavaScript"> the javascript here as it is in the jfiddle </script></head>

Comment: You should link to jQuery like `<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`. Make sure your path to jquery is correct. If you're using HTML5, you can drop the type="text/javascript" part.